# Chrome crazy with border spacing

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have tested and tested this over again.
In FF and IE9 this works fine, but in Chrome does not obey the following CSS.

```
 border-collapse: separate !important;
 border-spacing: 5px 15px !important;
```

Here's how it look like for 2 seconds... **AND THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD LOOK!**

[image]

***After that it becomes this?!?!***
[image]

You can try the site at www.polarpumpen.se/luftvarmepumpsguide

Comment: Can you build a minimal fiddle ? The `!important` might let us think that some rules aren't handled as well as they could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're making your `#searchtable` `display:inline`(stylesheet.css:30), It doesn't seem to serve a purpose so you can remove it ant the problem will go away.

Comment: Wow it worked.. Didn't know inline coudlt destroy border spacing? And in Chrome to.. :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this!  This is the satisfying end to multiple hours of frustrated googling about the same issue!! (how did you figure this out in 13 minutes????)